# A random element does not appear on the screen React + TS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm making a Cookie-type clicker. But I ran into such a problem that the pop-up element simply does not appear. Here is the code:

## Caravan.tsx

```
interface CaravanProps{
    x: number;
    y:number;
  }

function randomNumberBetween(min: number, max: number): number {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

export let CaravanGen = () => {
  let caravanList: Array<JSX.Element> = new Array<JSX.Element>();
  const[carList, setCarList] = useState(caravanList);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = randomNumberBetween(3000, 6000);
    let newCarList = carList;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const x = randomNumberBetween(0, 1900);
      const y = randomNumberBetween(0, 1000);
      newCarList.push(<Caravan x={x} y={y}/>);
      setCarList(newCarList);
      console.log(x, y);
    }, timer);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return(<div className='caravan-gen'>{caravanList}</div>);
}  
  
export function Caravan(props: CaravanProps) {
  
    return(
      <div style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left: props.x,
        top: props.y,
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        borderRadius: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "black"
      }}>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

## index.css

```
.caravan-pop{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

In Coockie Clicker A golden cookie appears in it at random intervals, which gives some bonuses. I want to implement the same thing so that my element appears in a random place on the screen and when I click on it, something will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixed it.

The problem was that when changing the array with JSX elements, the page was not updated. I have been studying React for no more than 3 months and my ignorance of working with webhooks affected here. To fix it, I left `carList` and `setCarList`. In the interval recorded a webhook:

```
setCarList(сarList => [
        ...сarList,
        <Caravan key={сarList.length} x={x} y={y} />
      ]);
```

Here is the corrected code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

interface CaravanProps{
    x?: number;
    y?:number;
  }

function randomNumberBetween(min: number, max: number): number {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

export let CaravanGen = () => {
  const[carList, setCarList] = useState([] as Array<JSX.Element>);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = randomNumberBetween(3000, 6000);

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const x = Math.round(randomNumberBetween(0, 1900));
      const y = Math.round(randomNumberBetween(0, 1000));
      setCarList(сarList => [
        ...сarList,
        <Caravan key={сarList.length} x={x} y={y} />
      ]);

      console.log(carList);
    }, timer);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [carList]);

  return(<div key={2} className='caravan-gen'>{carList}</div>);
}  
  
export function Caravan(props: CaravanProps) {
  
    return(
      <div style={{
        zIndex:10,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: `${props.x}px`,
        top:  `${props.y}px`,
        width: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        borderRadius: "55%",
        backgroundColor: "black"
      }}>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And a screenshot of the result I needed.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UAMF.png)

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Your `useEffect` hook call has no dependencies. Which means it will only run intially once and stops.

### Possible solution

Add `carList` into the dependency array. This might be the issue.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [carList]);
```

Hope this helps! Otherwise just comment below for more input.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your solution, but the problem was not solved. By the way, even without specifying `carList`, it did not work once, but works cyclically, as it should. This can be seen from the console in which I output random coordinates for my element.